# JButton remaining focused for too long

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am having a problem with a `JButton` named `saveChanges` remaining focused for too long when pressed, and I am not sure why this is happening. Below is an excerpt from my code:

```
saveChanges.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        saveChanges.setFocusPainted(false);
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));

        // execute some code which inserts records into a database

        setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
    }
}
```

The code in this method takes about 5-10 seconds to execute but for some reason the cursor returns to the default cursor state several seconds before the `saveChanges` button returns to its non-focused state and I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i think you need to execute database code separate thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing is a single threaded environment, anything that blocks the Event Dispatching Thread, used by Swing to process new events, including repaint requests, will cause the UI to look like it's frozen, because it is.

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Equally, Swing is not thread safe, this means that any updates made to the UI must be made from within the context of the EDT.

You could use a `SwingWorker` to do the long running process in the background (from within it's `doInBackground` method) and update the state of the UI by overriding it's `done` method, which is called from within the context of the EDT once the `doInBackground` method has exited.

Take a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have no experience with this but I will have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Non-GUI processes should be executed on a separate thread from the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to handle these operations.